# copy dependencies using two COPY statement in Dockerfile so it creates a new layer

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a 'lib' folder containing product and third party dependencies. I want to copy all dependencies to a same location using two COPY statements so that first layer will have third party dependencies and second layer will have internal dependencies.

Current code:

> COPY XXX/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib

Something I am seeking for:

> COPY XXX/BOOT_INF/lib/[internal-dependencies] /app/lib/
>
> COPY XXX/BOOT_INF/lib/[remaining-dependencies] /app/lib/

Internal dependencies starts with a common prefix 'abc'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Dockerfile reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

You can copy specific files starting with a pattern with:

```
COPY abc* /app/lib
```

More info about how Docker matches files in COPY operations: https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Match